# Return a reference of an object instance

Tags: php, object, instance, mptt

I'm working on a MPTT object that will support several database methods. First of is MySQL and MySQLi. Now I've created it like this

Mptt - The main object that will load the correct sub object

```
class Mptt {
/**
 * Array of available driver types
 * @var array
 */
private $availableDrivers = array('mysqli','mysql');

/**
 * Holding an instance of the mptt object corresponding to the selected driver
 * @var object
 */
public $instance;

public function __construct($driver = 'mysqli', $autoConnect = false, $info = array())  {
    if (in_array($driver, $this->availableDrivers)) {
        switch ($driver) {
            case 'mysqli':
                $this->instance =& new Mptt_MySQLi();
                break;

            case 'mysql':
                $this->instance =& new Mptt_MySQL();
                break;
        }

        return $this->instance;
    }
}
}
```

now, the only way i've been successfull in getting this working is to do something like

add public variables for each driver and do it like this

`$mptt = new Mptt('mysqli');`
`$mptt->mysqli->addBranch(.....);`

but i don't want that `mysqli-> part`.. So i thought if i maybe tried to pass the `$this->instance` as a refference then `$mptt` would reffer to `Mptt_MySQLi` instead..

Hopefully someone knows an answer to this..

Thanks in advance
- Ole

Comment: Check this out: http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, no need of `&` before `new`, as in PHP 5 objects are passed by reference by default.
What you are doing is correct, but you can't do this in the constructor, you have to define `getInstance()` method, which will construct your object and return the reference to `$this->instance`.

Comment: Also, i think i might use a more traditional interpretation of a driver here. Make the "driver" instance protected and only work through the `Mptt` class. This way you never need to know what driver you are working with as `Mptt` will provide a single consistent interface to all of its available drivers.

Comment: Not sure i fully understood what you mean about this?

Comment: Lol this was late.. Forgot I had asked and logged in now, and yeah.. Accepted this as the answer :) better late than never i guess